# display images from api on image show sliders

Tags: xcode, swift3, alamofire, slideshow

I downloaded [this](https://github.com/zvonicek/ImageSlideshow) library and my goal is to get images links from web service as Json then show them.

here is how to do it by a random link from the Internet

```
 let alamofireSource = [AlamofireSource(urlString:
 "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1432679963831-2dab49187847?w=1080")!, 
AlamofireSource(urlString: "https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1447746249824-    
4be4e1b76d66?w=1080")!,  
AlamofireSource(urlString: 
"https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1463595373836-6e0b0a8ee322?w=1080")!]
```

What I thought I should do is :

1- do a call request to my api

2- save images URLs in an array

3- loop through the array and have the variable in `[AlamofireSource(urlString:
 "variable from the array")!`

Is this the right way or is there any better way even without using this library ?

**Update**

```
  var Pics = [JSON]()

open override var supportedInterfaceOrientations: UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
    return .portrait
}

@IBOutlet var slideshow: ImageSlideshow!

override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    let url = "http://localhost:8000/api/hello"

    Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON { response in


        if let value: AnyObject = response.result.value as AnyObject? {
            //Handle the results as JSON
            let json = JSON(value)


            for (key, subJson) in json["pic"] {

                self.Pics.append(subJson) as? String

            }
            print(self.Pics)


        }
    }


}


 let kingfisherSource = [KingfisherSource(urlString: Pics)!] // error 


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    slideshow.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    slideshow.slideshowInterval = 5.0
    slideshow.pageControlPosition = PageControlPosition.underScrollView
    slideshow.pageControl.currentPageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.lightGray
    slideshow.pageControl.pageIndicatorTintColor = UIColor.black
    slideshow.contentScaleMode = UIViewContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    slideshow.currentPageChanged = { page in
        print("current page:", page)
    }
```

Note:

this is the format of the json data

```
[
"http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
"http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
"http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
"http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
"http://localhost:8000/images/1490104055.jpg",
null,
null
]
```

Thanks